# Firebase Loading to Different Nodes iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I'm trying to load my Description, Location, and Pic into the same AutoId to firebase.  I have to store the Pic first and then get the URL and then add the URL to the Pic value.  I tried to upload the Description and Location first, leave the Pic blank and then go back and add the Pic URL, but my key value for the autoID doesn't seem to be working.

It keeps putting the Pic URL into a different childAutoId.  How do I get them to store into the same child node?

**Initial function to create the AutoID node**

```
    @IBAction func postToWall(_ sender: Any) {
    let location : String = locationTextField.text!
    let description : String = descriptionTextField.text!


    self.ref.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(["Location" : location, "Description" : description, "Pic" : ""])

    let newRef = ref.child("Posts").childByAutoId()
    print(newRef)
    key = newRef.key
    print(key)
    savePicPost()
}
```

**After saving the pic to storage, trying to go back to the just created ID and save the Pic URL**

```
    func savePicPost(){
    //Store the image in storage
    let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
    let storedImage = storageRef.child("PostPics/").child(imageName)

    if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.postImage.image!) {
        storedImage.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            if let picPostURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {
                self.ref.child("Posts").child(self.key).updateChildValues(["Pic" : picPostURL], withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in

                    if error != nil{
                        print(error!)
                        return
                    }

                })
            }

        })
    }
}
```

And Here is how it's saving, into different IDs
[Firebase Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XMHY.png)

I'm close, I can feel it.  Something must be up with my key value though I think.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's clear and simple. You're storing a completely new child in `key`, not the one you used when you set values.

```
// This creates a new child
let newRef = ref.child("Posts").childByAutoId()
```

Instead, keep holding the reference to your `childByAutoId` and pass it to your `savePicPost()`. There you can use it to store your picture URL. i.e.

```
let post = self.ref.child("Posts").childByAutoId()
post.setValue(["Location" : location, "Description" : description, "Pic" : ""])

// call your method like so
func savePicPost(into: post)

// use this ref to update picture URL
post.updateChildValues(["Pic" : picPostURL])
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hmmmm, okay.  I don't quite understand it but let me play around with it and try to figure it out.  Thanks for the response

Comment: `childByAutoId()` basically returns `FirebaseDatabaseReference` and since you wanted to reuse it for later, you can hold reference to it and use it later in your `savePicPost()`. I don't have any Firebase project setup atm so couldn't post complete exact code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I see now.  Thank you.  I was creating a new ID instead of using the old one.  Here is what my code looks like now, I commented out what I deleted.  I actually deleted some to make it work.  Funny how that goes.  Thanks

```
@IBAction func postToWall(_ sender: Any) {
    let location : String = locationTextField.text!
    let description : String = descriptionTextField.text!
```

//        let newRef = ref.child("Posts").childByAutoId()
        let newRef = self.ref.child("Posts").childByAutoId()

//        self.ref.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(["Location" : location, "Description" : description, "Pic" : ""])

```
    newRef.setValue(["Location" : location, "Description" : description, "Pic" : ""])


    print(newRef)
    key = newRef.key
    print(key)
    savePicPost()
```

//        print(key)

```
}
```